# WebTest Cient's exchange() encoding url resulting in "Status expected:<200> but was:<404>". Is there any way i can stop it from encoding my URL

Tags: java, spring, url, spring-webflux

I am writing a consumer contract in spring using WebTestClient, When I am hitting the URL which contains context params, my test is failing saying expected 200 but the response it 404. It seems to me that when exchange() is called, it is encoding the URL resulting it in failure. The URL I am hitting is:-

> /v2/resolvedPoliciesOutcome?assetClass=ABC-ABC-ABC&contextParams=(courseId=1bf854,courseBssVer=1,ignoreOverrides=true)

```
 FluxExchangeResult<String> result = webTestClient.get().uri((uriBuilder -> 
                      uriBuilder.path(GET_COURSE_SETTING_SUCCESS_URL)
              .queryParam("assetClass","ABC-ABC-ABC")
                      .queryParam("contextParams"," 
                      (courseId=1bf854,courseBssVer=1,ignoreOverrides=true)")
                      .build()))
              .exchange()
                      .expectStatus().isOk().expectHeader()
                      .contentType(contentType).returnResult(String.class);
```

Output Coming:-

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>

> GET http://localhost:12830/lee/v2/resolvedPoliciesOutcome?assetClass=ABC-ABC-ABC&contextParams=(courseId%3D1bf854,courseBssVer%3D1,ignoreOverrides%3Dtrue)
> WebTestClient-Request-Id: [1]

No content

< 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: [text/plain]
< Transfer-Encoding: [chunked]
< Server: [Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)]
```

Comment: so: have you tried running the url in your browser? maybe you needed to have "/" before GET_COURSE_SETTING_SUCCESS_URL in your path(..) call

Comment: yes, I did... I am getting a response when I am hitting this URL in postman

Comment: Also tried both adding and removing "/". Did not work

Comment: and there is no difference between the url you hit in postman, and the one you hit through your code? the 404 error indicates otherwise.

Comment: No, there is no difference. The only difference I can notice is the URL it is generating in the console is encoded. So, i am guessing, the URL it is hitting is: **/v2/resolvedPoliciesOutcome?assetClass=ABC-ABC-ABC&contextParams=(courseId%3D1bf854,courseBssVer%3D1,ignoreOverrides%3Dtrue)**   instead of : **/v2/resolvedPoliciesOutcome?assetClass=ABC-ABC-ABC&contextParams=(courseId=1bf854,courseBssVer=1,ignoreOverrides=true)**

Comment: have you debugged your code and checked the value? have you checked the error message in your logs?

Comment: I have debugged it. Uri method is sending the correct URI template. It is getting encoded when exchange() of webtestclient is running. In exchange(), there is a method initRequestBuilder()  it doing the following: `URI uri = (this.uri != null ? this.uri : uriBuilderFactory.expand(""));
   return ClientRequest.create(this.httpMethod, uri)
     .headers(headers -> headers.addAll(initHeaders()))
     .cookies(cookies -> cookies.addAll(initCookies()))
     .attributes(attributes -> attributes.putAll(this.attributes));`  which is returning encoded URI